# Excel pivot table calculated fields - referring to other dimensions in equation?

Tags: excel, pivot

I'm struggling to find much useful documentation on Excel 2013 pivot table calculated fields.

My pivot table is fairly simple.  I have a 'Company' dimensions as rows (e.g. 'A', 'B' etc) and calendar weeks as columns `('1' --> '52')`. The value in the grid shows a date based status value.  For example, for Company 'A' there are date based state source rows that are shown under 'week 6', 'week 14' and so on.

What I'm trying to do is inject a value into this pivot table to replace blank/null values.  For instance,  for Company 'A' there are no values for weeks 7 thru 13.  In this case I want to inject a calculated field that looks for the last known value for Company 'A' and then uses that last know value. In this case the calculation for week 7 would detect that the value is null and find the last non-null value (week 6) and use that.  The equation might be something like:

```
derived state = if(State=0, if(previous non null value > 0, previous non  null value,0),0)
```

However, I can't find any docs that explain how to set up an equation that uses multiple dimension references and uses some form of lag or last known value finder function.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to fill in your null values.  Then use the new data as the source for your pivot table.  Below is a method of "copying" your data without modifying the original.

If this is your source data starting in cell A1:

```
1           2           3           4           5
1/1/2014    1/8/2014    1/15/2014   1/22/2014   1/29/2014
1/2/2014    1/9/2014    1/16/2014   1/23/2014   1/30/2014
1/3/2014    1/10/2014   1/17/2014       
1/4/2014    1/11/2014   1/18/2014
```

this formula in cell F2 and pasted across will fill in your blank cells in for week 4 and 5.

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,MAX(OFFSET(A2,0,-1*(A$1-1)):A2))
```

Step by step through the formula

- check that A2 is not blank
- if it isn't blank, copy the value in A2
- if it is blank, choose the max (most recent) date from that row

  - the max should suffice for getting the last non-null value if the week columns are chronologically ordered